# how to convert a timestamp to int in sql (vertica)

Tags: sql, vertica

I have a timestamp as `2017-07-19 11:45:01`and i want it to convert to int.

Query:

```
select cast(max(event_timestamp) as INT) from error_messages where error_level='ERROR' and user_name='git'
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [2366] [42846]: [Vertica][VJDBC](2366) ERROR: Cannot cast type timestamptz to int
  [Vertica][VJDBC](2366) ERROR: Cannot cast type timestamptz to int
    com.vertica.util.ServerException: [Vertica][VJDBC](2366) ERROR: Cannot cast type timestamptz to int
```

Comment: @Swat Use JULIAN_DAY function in Vertica to convert the time stamp to a integer value or big integer.

Comment: Thanks @RohitPadma

Comment: @Swat Your welcome ! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` this way:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'001-01-01 00:00:00', '2015-02-23 03:12:35');
 timestampdiff 
---------------
   63560257955
```

to get the number of **time units** you want (SECONDs here above) since the timestamp you want...

Comment: Does this work even when the end_timestamp is null. how can i get the number of minutes if i have only start_timestamp . I am trying to get the number of minutes a query is executing(start_timestamp looks like 2017-07-19 11:45:01)

Comment: You can measure the start/end distance using a generic *metric* only when you know both start and end positions. If end_timestamp is missing (alias NULL, alias unknown) the only option is to convert these NULLs into a generic "artificial" value using IFNULL/NVL/COALESCE. For example replacing end_timestamp - when NULL - with `current_timestamp`: `IFNULL(end_timestamp, current_timestamp)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get Unix Timestamp of that date as int than search fort that.
One option would be to calculate the range from your date to '1970-01-01' in seconds as int. This is the Unix Timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Use JULIAN_DAY function in Vertica to convert the time stamp to a integer value or number.

For more details refer Vertica documentation link: https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#16070.htm

To extract number from date time  with 1 second interval.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40-08');
```

Comment: `JULIAN_DAY` convert the DATE part returning the number of **days** since the beginning of the Julian calendar. In other words... you will lose the hour:minute:second.subsecond part

Comment: @mauro I consider day so updated the answer considering  seconds.

Comment: Assuming you want the number of seconds since the Epoch your edit is acceptable but... the returned value is a NUMERIC(18,6) and not an INTEGER.

Comment: As Integer was required i used Julian_day. Yes the returned value is numeric.